# Void means(V is capital)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

```
getJdbcTemplate().query(getFileContentSql, new RowMapper<Void>() {
    public void mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        OracleLobHandler lobHandler = new OracleLobHandler();
        InputStream inputStream = lobHandler.getBlobAsBinaryStream(rs, "file_content");
        ExlImporter importer = new ExlBOMImporter(inputStream);
        importer.process();
    }
}, fileId);
```

Please tell me what is Void ? 
Note : V is capital.

Answer (score 1):

Form the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html):

> The Void class is an uninstantiable placeholder class to hold a
>   reference to the Class object representing the Java keyword void.